# sails helpers and machine spec

Tags: sails.js, helper

I upgrade sails to the @^1.0.0 version and while I'm developing an API, I wanted to use a Service but the Sails document advice to use Helper now. And I don't realy use to work with the new way to discripe helper, build script or actions.

And all the try I have mad wasn't successful.

In the following exemple..

Here is my controller call:

```
    var ob = await ails.helpers.testy('sayHello');

    res.json({ob:ob});
```

helper

module.exports = {

```
friendlyName: 'Testy',


description: 'Testy something.',


inputs: {

  bla: {
    type: 'string'
  }

},


exits: {

  success: {

  }

},


fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

  console.log({blabla:inputs.bla})

  if(!inputs.bla) return exits.error(new Error('text not found'));

  var h = "Hello "+ inputs.bla;

  // All done.
  return exits.success(h);

}
```

};

I'm getting this error

```
error: A hook (`helpers`) failed to load!
error:
error: Attempted to `require('*-serv\api\helpers\testy.js')`, but an error occurred:
--
D:\*-serv\api\helpers\testy.js:28
  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
            ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function.......
```

and if I remove the "async" and the "await" form the Controller, the ob object return null and I'm having this error

````
WARNING: A function that was initially called over 15 seconds
ago has still not actually been executed.  Any chance the
source code is missing an "await"?

To assist you in hunting this down, here is a stack trace:
```
    at Object.signup [as auth/signup] (D:\*-serv\api\controllers\AuthController.js:106:26)
````

Comment: About removing the `async/await` part , you have to set the `sync` property to `true` so you can call the helper without `await`.

Comment: @HamzaFatmi in the module.exports ?

Comment: Yes in the helper definition.

Comment: not working too.. Do you maybe have some exemples of helpers use?

Answer (score 4):

The first guy from the comments is right.

After removing async from `fn: async function (inputs, exists) {};` you need to setup `sync: true` which is false by default. It is described [at helpers doc page](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers#?synchronous-helpers) at **Synchronous helpers** section.

So your code should look like this

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Testy',


  description: 'Testy something.',


  sync: true, // Here is essential part


  inputs: {

    bla: {
      type: 'string'
    }

  },


  exits: {

    success: {

    }

  },


  fn: function (inputs, exits) {

    console.log({blabla:inputs.bla})

    if(!inputs.bla) return exits.error(new Error('text not found'));

    var h = "Hello "+ inputs.bla;

    // All done.
    return exits.success(h);

  }


};
```

From the another side, you have a problem with **async/await**. The top most reason for this are

1. Not supported Node.js version - check that you current version support it
2. If you use [sails-hook-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-babel) or another Babel related solution, you may miss required plugin for async/await processing

Comment: Your sails solutions are super helpful thank you Pavlo!

Comment: I finaly beat the beast. Thank for help !